# image file upload not working on wamp server

Tags: php, html, upload

Here is my HTML code
"post.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my PHP code "upload.php"

```
<?php
target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
?>
```

and the result I am getting is

```
File is an image - image/jpeg.
```

There is no issue with execution of the files but the thing is whenever I uploads any file or image via html code the file does not comes up in the upload folder despite of successful execution of the code.

P.S I am using php7 on wampserver

Comment: where is the upload code???

Comment: Server by default uploads files to `tmp` directory, you need to move files to the desired directory.

Comment: @Sinto post.html is posting the image to upload.php

Comment: This might be a perfect time to read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use below code line before your code line `$uploadOk = 1;`

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);`

Like:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["upload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

While coping codes from some other sites please understand what is written in there and proceed. :-)

`$check = getimagesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);` this line of code used to get size of image & do a size validation.

Comment: thank you that solved the problem but $_FILES["fileToUpload"] should be $_FILES["upload"]

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :   


 <?php

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    target_dir = "upload/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: There should be `move_uploaded_file()` to upload a file to a target folder.

Comment: _"These things are happing on page load , and on page load you don't have any file"_ - The form and the PHP code are in different files, so the OP doesn't trigger this code unless it's posted from the form. Also, since the OP _does_ get the file type from the file, so the post obviously works. Your suggestion is good practice though, but it doesn't address the OP's current issue. The OP simply doesn't handle the uploaded file. (like moving it to the upload folder).